¿por que no sé despliega la aplicación echa en nodejs en plesk?
estoy tratando de subir una aplicación echa con Node.js en un un subdominio con Plesk, desafortunadamente, estoy teniendo un error el cual no puedo resolver. De acuerdo con el tutorial que vi, tengo que subir los archivos, dirigirme a la sección al dashboard de Node.js, especificar  la aplicación root en donde defino la ruta hacía la ruta de mi aplicación y el Application Startup File como index.js, ya que es el documento donde comienza o arranca mi aplicación.


